# batch windows command written in prompt but no execution

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

To avoid to repeat a task too often, I am setting up a batch file (in WINDOWS 10). It opens several CMD PROMPT to a specific Directory and launch a command.

For one case, I want the CMD PROMPT to open, to go to the specific directory and to set the COMMAND in the PROMPT without launching it. Then I'd just have to click on ENTER to launch that command whenever I want later on.

Here is my code:

```
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set CordovaProjPath="C:\MyPath\"
start cmd /k "cd /d %CordovaProjPath% && cordova build android"
```

With this code it launches the command "cordova build android".

If I go with `start cmd /k "cd /d %JCACordovaProjPath%` instead of `start cmd /k "cd /d %JCACordovaProjPath% && cordova build android"` **it gives me the PROMPT with: "C:\MyPath>", I'd like to write: "cordova build android" behind it without launching the command.**

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide repeatable execution (as mentioned in comments) you can put the relevant commands in a loop with a "quit" option:

```
@Echo Off
    setlocal
    Set "CordovaProjPath=C:\MyPath"
    Set "CommandToRun=cordova build android"
:loop
    Cd /D %CordovaProjPath%
    Echo %CommandToRun%
    set QUIT=
    set /p QUIT=Press ENTER to run command or 'Q' to quit:
    if /i "%QUIT%" == "Q" goto :eof
    %CommandToRun%
    goto :loop
```

Unlike the original, this runs the target command in the same command-window as the repeating loop. Depending on what the command in question does, this may be more attractive (less windows popping-up).  However, some commands may cause the main window to close; if this is the case, you can revert to running the command in its own window in one of two different ways.  In each case, replace the line:

```
    ...
    %CommandToRun%
    ...
```

**Run in own window and remain open**

```
    ...
    start "%CommandToRun%" /wait cmd /k %CommandToRun%
    ...
```

Using `/k` will leave the command-prompt window open after the target command has run -- this may be appropriate if you need to see the output of the command and it does not have its own pause.

**Run in own window then close**

```
    ...
    start "%CommandToRun%" /wait cmd /c %CommandToRun%
    ...
```

Using `/c` will mean the command-prompt will close after the target command has run.  This may be appropriate if you do not need to see the output of the command, or if it has its own pause.

Comment: some feedback regarding your answer: With the first case (just `%CommandToRun%` (CTR) on penultimate line) it exits when the program finishes it's execution. Second case, I substitued `start %CTR% /wait cmd /k %CTR%` with `start %CTR% /wait cmd /c %CTR%` and it works fine. Thanks for your input. Edit your answer and I'll validate it as the right one.

Comment: @nyluje Thanks for the feedback; I had considered mentioning `/c` but since you were originally using `/k` I didn't bother :-) ... edits made.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this do you:

```
@Echo Off
Set "CordovaProjPath=C:\MyPath"
Set "CommandToRun=cordova build android"
Start "%CommandToRun%" Cmd /K "Cd /D %CordovaProjPath%&Echo %CommandToRun%&Pause>Nul&%CommandToRun%"
```

Below is an alternative which may allow for your alternative double-quoting method:

```
@Echo Off
Set CordovaProjPath="C:\MyPath"
Set CommandToRun="cordova build android"
Start %CommandToRun% Cmd /K "(Cd /D %CordovaProjPath%)&(Echo %CommandToRun%)&(Pause>Nul)&(%CommandToRun%)"
```

Comment: This does the job (I wished I could call back the command hitting the arrow key up once it is executed in the prompt, like CLI mode, but that was not specified in my question). I think you're missing a % in front of the CommandToRun at `Echo CommandToRun%`. Correct that and I'll validate your answer (I could not edit it myself because one need to edit 6 chars min). Also if I've tried to change `"CommandToRun=cordova build android"` to `CommandToRun="cordova build android"` this does not work, do you have any comment about that or link to explain it?

Comment: You could add `:loop` above the `Start` command, and `goto :loop` below it ... it will repeatedly prompt to run the command every time you press ENTER (use Ctrl-C to stop it).  If you want to get clever, look at the `SET /P` command (see `SET /?`) to read a value and conditionally loop back without needing to Ctrl-C.  Re. the last part -- "_Also if I've tried to change..._" Why do you _want_ to change it if it's working?  The form used allows a value to be stored that includes spaces, but _doesn't_ store any `"..."` around it. The form you're trying stores the double-quotes .../cont

Comment: ... which breaks things because it's looking for a command with embedded spaces (`cordova build android`) rather than the command `cordova` with two parameters (`build` and `android`).

Comment: Edited to fix the missing percent as noted and requested.

Comment: @TripeHound `:loop` around `start` made it a non stop loop with no conditional to exit the loop (had to reset the machine).

Comment: @nyluje My bad - I'd forgotten the `pause` was in a new shell.  Changing `Cmd` to `/wait Cmd` in the `Start` command should help, or see my answer for an alternative.